# How to create a screenshots Motion JPEG Streaming Server with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, streaming, mjpeg

Here is a screenshots M-JPEG Streaming Server I found through internet:
<kbd>[Demo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server)</kbd>

the source code build in C# that I'm not familiar.

can anyone give me some advice how to do the same program using python?

I have tried socketserver but not sure what to do next to create screenshots streaming :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import time
import argparse
import cv2 
import socket as Socket
import os
import re

# camera = None
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


 def getIP(iface):
     search_str = 'ip addr show wlan0'.format(iface) # desktop: enp2s0
     ipv4 = re.search(re.compile(r'(?<=inet )(.*)(?=\/)', re.M), os.popen(search_str).read()).groups()[0]
     ipv6 = re.search(re.compile(r'(?<=inet6 )(.*)(?=\/)', re.M), os.popen(search_str).read()).groups()[0]
     return (ipv4, ipv6)


# def setUpCameraPi(win=(320, 240)):
    # global camera
    # camera = Camera('pi')
    # camera.init(win=win)


# def setUpCameraCV(win=(320, 240), cv=0):
    # global camera
    # camera = Camera('cv')
    # camera.init(cameraNumber=cv, win=win)


def compress(orig, comp):
    return float(orig) / float(comp)


class mjpgServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """
    A simple mjpeg server that either publishes images directly from a camera
    or republishes images from another pygecko process.
    """

    ip = None
    hostname = None

    def do_GET(self):
        global camera
        print('connection from:', self.address_string())

        if self.ip is None or self.hostname is None:
            self.ip, _ = getIP('wlan0') # desktop: enp2s0
            self.hostname = Socket.gethostname()

        if self.path == '/mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header(
                'Content-type',
                'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary'
            )
            self.end_headers()

            while True:
                if camera:
                    # print('cam')
                    ret, img = camera.read()

                else:
                    raise Exception('Error, camera not setup')

                if not ret:
                    print('no image from camera')
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue

                ret, jpg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
                # print 'Compression ratio: %d4.0:1'%(compress(img.size,jpg.size))
                self.wfile.write("--jpgboundary".encode("utf-8"))
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg')
                # self.send_header('Content-length',str(tmpFile.len))
                self.send_header('Content-length', str(jpg.size))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(jpg.tostring())
                # time.sleep(0.05)

        elif self.path == '/':
            # hn = self.server.server_address[0]
            port = self.server.server_address[1]
            ip = self.ip
            hostname = self.hostname

            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>'.encode("utf-8"))
            # self.wfile.write('<h1>{0!s}[{1!s}]:{2!s}</h1>'.format(hostname, ip, port).encode("utf-8"))
            self.wfile.write('<img src="http://{}:{}/mjpg"/>'.format(ip, port).encode("utf-8"))
            # self.wfile.write('<p>{0!s}</p>'.format((self.version_string())).encode("utf-8"))
            # self.wfile.write('<p>The mjpg stream can be accessed directly at:<ul>')
            # self.wfile.write('<li>http://{0!s}:{1!s}/mjpg</li>'.format(ip, port))
            # self.wfile.write('<li><a href="http://{0!s}:{1!s}/mjpg"/>http://{0!s}:{1!s}/mjpg</a></li>'.format(hostname, port))
            # self.wfile.write('</p></ul>')
            # self.wfile.write('<p>This only handles one connection at a time</p>'.encode("utf-8"))
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>'.encode("utf-8"))

        else:
            print('error', self.path)
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>')
            self.wfile.write('<h1>{0!s} not found</h1>'.format(self.path))
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>')

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""
    
def handleArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A simple mjpeg server Example: mjpeg-server -p 8080 --camera 4')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', help='mjpeg publisher port, default is 9000', type=int, default=9000)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--camera', help='set opencv camera number, ex. -c 1', type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--type', help='set camera type, either pi or cv, ex. -t pi', default='cv')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--size', help='set size', nargs=2, type=int, default=(320, 240))

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    args['size'] = (args['size'][0], args['size'][1])
    return args


def main():
    args = handleArgs()

    try:
        win = args['size']
        # if args['type'] is 'cv':
            # cv = args['camera']
            # setUpCameraCV(cv=cv, win=win)
        # else:
            # setUpCameraPi(win=win)
        # server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', args['port']), mjpgServer)
        ipv4, ipv6 = getIP('wlan0') # desktop: enp2s0
        print('wlan0:', ipv4)
        mjpgServer.ip = ipv4
        mjpgServer.hostname = Socket.gethostname()
        # server = HTTPServer((ipv4, args['port']), mjpgServer)
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer((ipv4, 9000), mjpgServer)
        print("server started on {}:{}".format(Socket.gethostname(), args['port']))
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')
        server.socket.close()
    server.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does this send the bytes of screenshot?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA not yet,i don't know how to crate screenshot bytes

Comment: So your problem is how to get the bytes of screenshot, right?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA not exactly,I also not sure what I have try is correct,maybe there is another method of create socket server.